# complete() in R for 6-month dates

Tags: r, date

I have data in 6-month intervals (ID, 6-month-start-date, outcome value), but for some IDs, there are half years where the outcome is missing. Simplified example:

```
id = c("aa", "aa", "ab", "ab", "ab")
date = as.Date(c("2021-07-01", "2022-07-01", "2021-07-01", "2022-01-01", "2022-07-01"))
col3 = c(1,2,1,2,1)

df <- data.frame(id, date, col3)
```

For similar datasets where the date is monthly, I used `complete(date = seq.Date(start date, end date, by = "month")` to fill the missing months and add 0 to the outcome field in the 3rd column.

I could do the following and expand the data to monthly, then create a new 6-month-start-date column, group by it and ID, and sum col3.

```
df_complete <- df %>% group_by(id) %>%
  complete(date = seq.Date(as.Date(min(date)), as.Date(max(date) %m+% months(5)), by="month")) %>% 
  mutate (col3 = replace_na(col3, 0))

df_complete_6mth <- df_complete %>% mutate(
  halfyear =  ifelse(as.integer(format(date, '%m')) <= 6, 
                                 paste0(format(date, '%Y'), '-01-01'),
                                 paste0(format(date, '%Y'), '-07-01'))) %>%
  group_by(id, halfyear) %>%
  summarise(col3_halfyear = sum(col3))
```

However, is there a solution where the "by =" argument specifies 6 months? I tried

```
df_complete <- df %>% group_by(id) %>%
  complete(date = seq.Date(as.Date(min(date)), as.Date(max(date) %m+% months(5)), by="months(6)")) %>% 
  mutate (col3 = replace_na(col3, 0))
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: What is your expected / desired output?

Comment: Does `df %>%  group_by(id) %>% complete(date = seq.Date(min(date), max(date), by="6 month"), fill = list(col3 = 0))` give the expected output?

Comment: @JonSpring Learned something new here: `by="6 month"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the help for `seq.Date`:

> **by** can be specified in several ways.
>
> A number, taken to be in days.
>
> A object of class difftime
>
> A character string, containing one of "day", "week", "month",
> "quarter" or "year". This can optionally be preceded by a (positive or
> negative) integer and a space, or followed by "s".

So I expect you want:

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)
df %>%  
 group_by(id) %>% 
 complete(date = seq.Date(min(date), max(date), by="6 month"), 
          fill = list(col3 = 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like this.  You make a sequence of dates by month and then take every sixth one after the first one?

```r
library(lubridate)
dates <- seq(mdy("01-01-2020"), mdy("01-01-2023"), by="month")
dates[seq(1, length(dates), by=6)]
#> [1] "2020-01-01" "2020-07-01" "2021-01-01" "2021-07-01" "2022-01-01"
#> [6] "2022-07-01" "2023-01-01"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>